# Homestead: Cannot start

Tags: windows-8, vagrant

I cannot seem to get my box working properly. [I'm following the instructions here.](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead)

I'm running Windows 8.1 64-bit.

When I run `vagrant up`, it goes through a series of commands and logs a bunch of stuff, but ultimately just returns the console to me. When I try to go to 192.168.10.10, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in Chrome

The last logs are are:

```
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    # Removed sharing folders......
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

Looking at VirtualBox Manager, the preview display shows it at login stage:

[image]

My `Vagrantfile`:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

    # config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    #   vb.gui = true
    # end


    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
    elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
    end

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end


end
```

My `Homestead.yaml`

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\myfolder
      to:  /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: joineval.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to `127.0.0.1:8000` or `localhost:8000` instead. That forwards to the web server in the VM guest.

Comment: Just tried; it didn't work. I get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`